# Floating Action Button blocking other components

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

The new Material Design of Google recommends to use floating action buttons to draw attention to the user for the main action on that screen. There are quite a lot of examples of this within a list view.

Now, suppose your list view has just enough items to fill the screen, making scrolling impossible. If your list items have a certain component that the user can interact with, for example a switch or a favorite star, its possible that the floating action button is blocking this component. How should we handle this case?

**EDIT**: This actually **always** happens with the last item in your list

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a blank View with the same height as floating button in footer of list. So when you scroll your list, last item will come up and floating button will not hide last item of list. This is a simple and quick solution.

Answer (score 5):

I just do what I think the Google Gmail app is doing and add padding to the RecyclerView (or ListView). Remember to set `clipToPadding` to `false` so that the `RecyclerView` behaves correctly when it is inside a `CoordinatorLayout`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
    android:id="@+id/my_recyclerview" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:clipToPadding="false" 
    android:paddingBottom="100dp" />
```

Comment: if i implement this then animation is not applied to the layout!

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue now, and I solved it this way:

```
public void addBlankSpace(ListView listView)
{
    Space space = new Space(listView.getContext());
    space.setMinimumHeight(Core.dpToPx(50));
    listView.addFooterView(space);
}
```

And I guess there is always a better way. like checking if you even need it. and only then to display it. but for now, this simple code works just fine.

And here is the conversion function:

```
public static int dpToPx(int dp)
{
    return (int)(dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

Or we can just add some padding:

```
listView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, Core.dpToPx(50));
```

Comment: Why not just use XML: `paddingBottom="50dp"` ?

Answer (score 0):

While loading the list, You can create a flag and find if the item in the list is last visible item in the screen,than hide the floating button.

use this to find last visible item

```
int currentPosition = list.getLastVisiblePosition();
```

You will get the last number of the item.i.e if 7th item is last visible in your list,than it will return value of currentPosition = 7;

Once you get the number of items that fit in your screen,Now check for the flag

```
if(listAdapterItemsArray.get(position) == currentPosition) {
    //hide button
} else {
    //nothing 
}
```

Comment: What will happen if you only have 7 items in the list, they are all displayed, the list can't be scrolled but you hide the button, so it doesn't overlap the last item?

Comment: Exactly.Just hide the button when list is fitting enough on the screen.

Comment: Wouldn't you then lack the button's functionality?

Comment: I said what the guy wanted.I know this kills some functionalities but its not recommended.But this guy needs to hide it anyway so i suggested a way to do that.Thats it.

Comment: He didn't want to simply hide the button, but handle the case where you cannot scroll the button away. It'd be bad to loose the primary action the FAB is used for.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position of google action button to left top using

```
     `android:layout_gravity="top|left"`
```

This way it looks good and doesn't hide anything.

Comment: Using `top|left` moves the button on top of the first list element.

Answer (score 0):

Add bottom padding to the `RecyclerView`. Also, don't use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` unless you've overridden `onMeasure`in the `layout manager`. Current layout managers do not yet **support** wrap content.

Add the attribute `android:clipToPadding="false"` to achieve the goal. As mentioned in comments.